# Limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}(\sqrt[n]{3}-\sqrt[n]{2})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I've stumbled across this problem:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}(\sqrt[n]{3}-\sqrt[n]{2})$$ Intuition tells me that the square root infinity is weaker than the nth root zero, also $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{3n^{n/2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{2n^{n/2}}$ probably. Any way to prove it properly? *I don't know Mr. L'Hospital yet, don't use him please*

Comment: Quick suggestion: search for a common denominator...

Comment: If expansion is allowed, $$\displaystyle3^{\frac1n}=\left(\frac13\right)^{-\frac1n}$$  $$=\left(1-\frac23\right)^{-\frac1n}=1+\frac2{3n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: What does the last equality mean? I don't understand. Be gentle, I'm a noob.

Comment: The $O$ represents [big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).  It refers to how fast terms are growing.  As $n\to\infty$, $1/n^2$ is negligible compared to $2/(3n)$, so there's no need to write out any more terms in expansion.

Comment: So this leads me to $\infty (1-1)$, right? But that's indeterminate.

Comment: Inside the brackets you find yourself with $ 1+ \frac{2}{3n} - 1 - \frac{1}{2n} = \frac{1}{6n}$. Multiply this with $\sqrt{n}$ and deduce the limit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n} (3^{\frac{1}{n}} - 2^{\frac{1}{n}}) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523876/proof-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-sqrtn-3-frac1n-2-frac1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sqrt n(\sqrt[n] 3-\sqrt[n] 2)=\frac{\sqrt n(\sqrt[n] 3-\sqrt[n] 2)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 3^{k/n}2^{1-(k+1)/n}\right)}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 3^{k/n}2^{1-(k+1)/n}}=\frac{\sqrt n}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 3^{k/n}2^{1-(k+1)/n}}$$
Note that $1\le3^{k/n}2^{1-(k+1)/n}\le 3$ for $0\le k\le n-1$, so the sum $S$ satisfies $n\le S\le3n $.

Therefore $$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt n}{3n}\le&\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt n}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 3^{k/n}2^{1-(k+1)/n}}\le\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt n}{n}\\0\le&\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt n}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 3^{k/n}2^{1-(k+1)/n}}\le 0\\&\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt n}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 3^{k/n}2^{1-(k+1)/n}}=0\\&\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt n(\sqrt[n]{3}-\sqrt[n] 2)=0\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh, beautiful. Thanks. Is there any way to prove the inequalities?

Comment: $3^{k/n}2^{1-k/n}\le 3^{k/n}3^{1-k/n}=3$ and $3^{k/n}2^{1-k/n}\ge 2^{k/n}2^{1-k/n}=2$

Comment: Just a detail - the sum should be $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}3^{k/n}2^{1-(k+1)/n}$

Comment: And you get $n\le S\le 3n$ which leads to the same result

Comment: I corrected it.

Comment: Thanks. Still $2n\le S$ is not true.

Comment: Should be replaced with $n\le S$, because $3^{k/n}2^{1-(k+1)/n}\ge 2^{k/n}2^{1-(k+1)/n}=2^{1-1/n}\ge 2^0=1$

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=\frac 1 n$ and $f(x)=3^x-2^x$ so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}(\sqrt[n]{3}-\sqrt[n]{2})=\lim_{x\to0} \sqrt x\frac{3^x-2^x}{ x}=\lim_{x\to0} \sqrt x\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{ x}=\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt{x} f'(0)=0$$

Comment: The last thing is derivative, right? I can't use that yet. It should be possible to solve it with basic algebra and limit arithmetics.

Comment: How do you prove the validity of the last two steps? Shouldn't you need to say that $\lim ab = \lim a \times \lim b$ in order to write $f'(0)$? In which case you have an indefinite limit of the form $\infty \times 0$... However I really like the idea!

Comment: @user88595 The derivative $f'(0)=\log(3)3^x-\log(2)2^x\Big|_{x=0}=\log(3)-\log(2)$ is finite so we haven't an indefinite limit of the form $0\times\infty$.

Comment: I stupidly assumed that $x\longrightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Elementary:

It is known that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}=\ln a, a>0.$$
Follow$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}(\sqrt[n]{3}-\sqrt[n]{2})= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}(\frac{\sqrt[n]{3}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}-\frac{\sqrt[n]{2}-1}{\frac{1}{n}})=0(\ln3-\ln2)=0.$$